# Modeling Halley's comet trajectory in Matlab

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, computational-physics, software

i'm writing a function that can plot the solution of a 2-body problem using the ode45 built-in function to solve the equation of motion:

$\frac {d^2 u}{d^2θ} + u = -\frac {μ}{l^2} \frac{1}{u^2} F(1/u)$

where u = 1/r the radial distance

l is the angular momentum

and $F(1/u) = GMm u^2$

replacing the force in the above equation I would get for the equation of motion:

$\frac {d^2 u}{d^2θ} + u = \frac{-Gm^2M}{l^2} - u$

where I have approximated μ by m.

my matlab code to solve this is the following:

```
function [dydt] = CentralF(o, y)
M = 1.9*10^30;
m = 2.2*10^14;
l = 1.1*10^3;
G = 6.67*10^-11;

dydt = [y(2); -(G*(m^2)*(M))/(l^2) - y(1)];
end
```

and I'm calling the function using:

```
>>[T, S] = ode45(@CentralF, -pi:0.001:pi, [-10, 10], foptions);
>>r = (S(:, 1));
>>x = r.*cos(T);
>>y = y = r.*sin(T);
>>plot(x, y);
```

The initial conditions are that of Halley's comet.

I should get an ellipse but I'm getting a cardioid instead. I don't know where is the problem.
Sorry if it's confusing, i'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I think it's great to include the code in the question, but for those of us unfamiliar with `matlab` some explanation / documentation would be helpful!

Comment: ah no problem. the method is by dividing the ODE of second order into 2 of first order, then using a runge kutta method to solve the two equations. I wrote the 2 ODEs in a way that a built in function called ode45 can understand them. the output is the solution of the 2 odes, one of which is the solution for u. so I converted the result to Cartesian coordinates and plotted x versus y

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: This is a programming question, not physics.

Comment: Where did the $-u$ come from in your last eqn? If you know the answer is an ellipse, why not plot the trajectory from the polar or Cartesian equation for an ellipse?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about debugging/re-writing code and not physics.

Answer (score 2):

I am not very familiar with the `ode45` function, but it seems to me that the equation you are solving is an equation in $u$; it is reasonable to assume the values returned are $u$ as a function of $\theta$. If that is so, then after solving your equation you should not treat $u$ as though it is $r$. I believe you need

```
r = 1./S(:,1);
```

Then you can compute `x` and `y` and plot...

Comment: thank you. I was doing that before, but  getting completely absurd results. plotting u versus theta is the only thing that's giving either a circle or a cardioid(which should be an ellipse). but youre right it makes more sense that way. i'll try again

Comment: Where do your initial conditions for $y$ come from? `[-10,10]` seems both arbitrary, and of completely the wrong order of magnitude.